# Pass Date to a C program from Shell Script

Tags: bash

I want to pass the date entered by a user in format YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS to the C program which further makes the entry in the DB.
When I am passing the entered date in the command line argument as '2010/07/15 12:13:14', the C program considers this as 2 arguments and not 1. We are using getopt function to fetch the command line argument. Also tried sending the date in " " qootes also.
Can anyone help me so that the complete argument will be treated as 1 and not 2.

Thanks

---

Below is the piece of code that I am executing:

```
name="Rahul+Kapgate arg"
temp=$name
./a.out -a "$temp"
#temp1="-a \"$name\""
#temp1=`echo $temp |sed 's/ /+/g'`
cmd="a.out -a \"${temp}\""
echo $cmd
exec $cmd
```

### Output

```
Rahul+Kapgate arg
a.out -a "Rahul+Kapgate arg"
"Rahul+Kapgate
```

Comment: You need to post the part of the shell script where you pass the arguments - it sounds like it's just a quoting problem (i.e. you're losing the quoting before it gets to the C program).

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the entire input in double quotes so it would be interpreted as one.

e.g., `program "2010/07/15 12:13:14"`