# Passing parameter through Shell to C

Tags: bash

```
name="Rahul Kapgate arg"
temp=$name
./a.out -a "$temp"
```

This will give me a following output :: `Rahul Kapgate arg`

Instead of `./a.out -a "$temp"` if i put following logic then it is generating differant output.

```
cmd="./a.out -a \"$temp\""
$cmd
```

Output :: `"Rahul`

[ a.out is nothing but the printing the 1st parameter through C unsing optarg())

I am expecting to generate the same output using 2nd option plz help me.

Comment: Bash FAQ <a href="http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050">entry #50</a>

Comment: The title of the question really isn't about passing parameters to C; the results would be the same regardless of the language.  Perhaps "Executing a bash variable as a command" or something along those lines would be better.

Comment: Is this in some way related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253198/pass-date-to-a-c-program-from-shell-script) by a different user?

Answer (score 1):

As the information in [the link provided by Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254907/passing-parameter-through-shell-to-c/3255003#3255003) indicates, you should try to avoid putting commands in variables. However, this may work for you (based also on information there):

```
cmd="./a.out"
args=(-a "$temp")
$cmd "${args[@]}"
```